# Application was not properly initialized at startup (JSF 1.2, WS 7)

Tags: jsf, websphere-7

i have developed an application using jsf 1.2. it worked fine with apache tomcat 6. i   took the war file on  production with websphere 7 and deployed the application. i recieved following error.

```
E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0100E: Uncaught init() 
exception created by servlet Faces Servlet in application Products_war:  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup,  
could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
```

my classpath file has following entries

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" 
path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre6"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" 
path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget
/Apache Tomcat v6.0"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

i have made following tries after googling till now..

```
including following listener in web.xml
<listener>   
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>   
</listener>
```

and removed jsf-api and jsf-impl from the lib folder of my application but to no avail.

plz help.
thanks in advance

Comment: Jamal could you please let me know the steps followed for running jsf 1.1 on was 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAS 7 already ships with JSF 1.2 bundled which can be either the "Sun RI" (Mojarra) or "MyFaces" (from Apache) implementation which is configureable in the WAS admin console. You need to remove the JSF JAR files from `/WEB-INF/lib` and you need to remove the listener from the `web.xml`.

#### See also:

- [WAS 7 developer guide - Configuring JavaServer Faces implementation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tweb_jsf.html)

Comment: there is no jsf JAR in my lib folder further, you want me to remove the listener that i mentioned above from my web.xml?

Comment: i have my-faces-api.jar and my-faces-impl.jar in my lib, should i remove these? i dont have jsf.jar in my lib folder

Comment: Yes, that's from MyFaces. Remove them. That you've had them both (MyFaces and Mojarra) in the first place is also not good. I wonder that it worked in Tomcat, it should fail over there as well.

Comment: you got me....i will try it when i hit the production environment tomorrow........

Comment: hi BalucC. i just set the class loading option to (parent last) and it resolved. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check: We have myfaces configured as a shared library on WebSphere. In troubleshooting my local configuration I had to set the shared library to "**Use an isolated class loader for this shared library**"

This is identified as part of the requirements for running a third-party JSF implementer:

Be Aware: If the you want to use a third party JSF implementation that is not shipped with the product, then:

1. Keep the configuration set to the SUN RI.
2. Add the third party listener to the web.xml file that is required.
3. Add the third party implementation Java archive (JAR) files to the
   application as an isolated shared library.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tweb_jsf.html

Maybe this will help someone if the first answer doesn't work for them.