# JSF2 IllegalStateException during server startup

Tags: jsf-2

I'm using JSF2.0 (Mojarra 2.0.6) under WAS7 application server. My web module facet is set to support (servlet API) version - 2.5. Also Im using RSA8.0.4.
I can see below exception during server start-up. Can any one suggest?

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0100E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet Faces Servlet in application FATCAKycApplication: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:851)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:309)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:219)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984578/application-was-not-properly-initialized-at-startup-jsf-1-2-ws-7) is very similar to what you are experiencing, you could try the approach described in BalusC's answer

Comment: No AndaP. That suggestion will not work in my case. In that forum issue is with JSF1.2 under WAS7. In my case Im using JSF2.0 (Mojarra 2.0.6) and infact I've placed Mojarra jars in my WEB-INF\lib folder. And have overrided WAS7 default jsf implementation by setting class loading policy to PARENT_LAST.

Comment: @Vamsi, did you also remove other container specific jars as mentioned in this answer [pretty-faces-config-issues-on-websphere-application-server-jsf2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019464/pretty-faces-config-issues-on-websphere-application-server-jsf2/12073347#12073347)..also  related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718934/can-jsf-2-0-be-used-with-websphere-application-server-version-7-x

Comment: yeah. but still im facing the same issue. can u suggest any alternative sol pls?